# $routeProvider and sub directory angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have next project structure:

[image]

And my application hosts in sub directory `/my-scripts/vk.plants` (this mean, when i request this url- it loads layout.html and return to user).

`layout.html` has next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>   
        <script src="/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular/app/app.js"></script>
        <!-- include controllers and services -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Angular Layout!!</h1>

        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and `app.js` contains this:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/my-scripts/vk.plants', {
                controller: 'home.controller',
                templateUrl: '/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular/app/templates/home.html'
            });
    });
})(angular);
```

When i try to open `http://my-url/my-scripts/vk.plants` i got message from `layout.html`, but requests to my `templates/home.html` is not processed and nothing from this template display:

[image]

I am really confused with angular routing, because, by the way, there aren't any of errors in console. Is there any explanation?

**What i need:** when i open `http://my-url/my-scripts/vk.plants` i would like to set default controller and view for this url in angular as `home.controller` and `home.html`.

Comment: angular routing starts after the hash in url and has nothing to do with directory structure on server. Use `.when('/'` for your default

Answer (score 1):

okay. Look what you can do according to your paths.
(I'd suggest you to change your controller name from 'home.controller' to 'homeCtrl'(for simplicity)
(Note: still you can go with home.controller but better to follow suggested way)
I'm showing you with home.controller...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>   
        <script src="/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular/app/app.js"></script>


           //INCLUDE starCtrl.js (you have to create this)
           //include home.controller.js 


        <!-- include controllers and services -->
    </head>

    <body   ng-controller="startCtrl">     // initialize startCtrl here
        <h1>Angular Layout!!</h1>

        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

startCtrl.js

```
app.controller('startCtrl',function(){
     $location.url('home')     //startCtrl gets initialized and it redirects you to home (it will check for defined routes
}) ;
```

Now, to your app.js

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {                 //home route found
                controller: 'home.controller',   //controller will be applied
                templateUrl: '/my-scripts/vk.plants/public/static/scripts/angular/app/templates/home.html'  // user will be redirected to this page.
            });
    });
})(angular);
```

I hope this will work. Here with startCtrl you can do many things which you might not be knowing now. but it will help you a lot. Follow this n let me know if it doesn't work or console gives you any error.

Answer (score 1):

I've decide my problem next way:

1. Append `base` element into `layout.html`:

   ```
   <base href="/my-scripts/vk.plants/" />

   <script src="public/static/scripts/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="public/static/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

   <script src="public/static/scripts/angular/app/app.js"></script>
   ```
2. Change module configuration like this:

   ```
   (function(angular) { 'use strict'; 
   var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
               controller: 'home.controller',
               templateUrl: 'public/static/scripts/angular/app/templates/home.html'
           })
           .when('/factor', {
               controller: 'factor.controller',
               templateUrl: 'public/static/scripts/angular/app/templates/factor.html'
           });
   });
   ```

   })(angular);

Here is result:

[image]